# In .NET Core/.NET 5+, how do I set the transaction isolation level of a TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, .net-6.0

In .NET Core/.NET 5+, **how do I set the transaction isolation level of a [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)?**  In .NET Framework, it seems you could pass a TransactionOptions instance into the TransactionScope creation, but now it seems that isn't an option.

```cs
try {
    using (TransactionScope transaction = new(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {  
        UpdateTable1();
        UpdateTable2();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
} catch { ... }
```

(The background: It appears that I am having deadlocks on transactions that run as SERIALIZABLE, which seems to be the default when using a C# TransactionScope, and as a partial remedy, I wonder if having READ COMMITTED on all TransactionScopes would help.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you constrain your transaction scope to a single batch or procedure?

Comment: I don't use stored procedures; I use transaction scopes to allow rollback if .NET or database errors occur after a database write that would make subsequent writes moot.

Comment: Please show us your code. And which ADO.NET library are you using: `System.Data.SqlClient`, or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, or something else?

Comment: There you go; hope it helps.  I'm using Dapper with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but I'm thinking that might not matter.

Comment: Methinks in this situation you should be using the `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()` method instead of using `Transaction`'s ctor. It has an overload that accepts `IsolationLevel`.

Comment: It's not a Transaction, it's a TransactionScope.  Are you familiar?

Comment: I'll admit I'm not, sorry - I only ever use `Transaction` directly (or `TRANSACTION` in T-SQL), I've never needed to use `TransactionScope`.

Comment: They're pretty neat.  OK, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.-ctor?view=net-5.0#system-transactions-transactionscope-ctor(system-transactions-transactionscopeoption-system-transactions-transactionoptions-system-transactions-transactionscopeasyncflowoption)) accepting [`TransactionOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionoptions?view=net-5.0):

```cs
using var tr = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
    },
    TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
```

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski the link is fixed. The used constructor in the doc is marked as available since .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski [here is dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kNf5N1) for .NET 3.1

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  I think it got lost in the sea of overloads.